# showDatePicker theme change not working after update?

Tags: flutter

I'm setting the theme of showDatePicker using the builder function:

```
showDatePicker(
  initialDate: initialDate,
  firstDate: initialDate,
  lastDate: maxDate,
  context: context,
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.orange,
          accentColor: Colors.orange,
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            buttonColor: Colors.orange,
            splashColor: Colors.orange,
            colorScheme:
                ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
                    accentColor:
                        Colors.orange),
          ),
        ),
        child: child);
  },
);
```

This used to work on an older version of flutter (v1.12.13+hotfix.8), but on the current version (v1.17.5) does not work any longer.

I've also tried wrapping the whole function call with the custom theme

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange),
    child: MaterialButton(onTap: () {time = await ShowDatePicker (...)}
```

But this also does not alter the date picker theme.

Is this a bug or is there another method to change the theme now?

What should the call to set a custom theme for showDatePicker be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `colorScheme` and `buttonTheme` for the `ThemeData` inside the `builder` of the `showDatePicker`:

```
showDatePicker(
        initialDate: initialDate,
        firstDate: initialDate,
        lastDate: maxDate,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
              colorScheme:
              ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.redAccent),
              buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                  textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        });
```

Result:

[image: img]